# Microsoft Office Interop Excel won't copy to the Clipboard

Tags: excel, ms-word, .net-core, interop

I'm doing a small project (.net Core MVC). One thing won't work for me; I've tried numerous threads on Stack Overflow.

What I want to do is: Copy the data from an Excel sheet to a Word document. I'm using the Office Interop nuget to do so. I tried this in an console app (.Net) and got it to work. Now I'm trying to do the same in Core but it isn't working.

Instead of copying the data from the excel sheet it keeps copying my clipboard.

I use the following code (but as I mentioned I tried multiple solutions). Report is an instance of Word. The excel instance is visable in the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        string workbookPath = @"....\incidenten_aangemaakt.xlsx";


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excelApplication.Application.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        ws.Select();
        ws.Range["a1", "d6"].Copy();
        excelApplication.Quit();
        Document report = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"....\exceltest.docx");
        report.Bookmarks["test"].Range.PasteExcelTable(false, false, false);
        Console.Write("Done");
        report.SaveAs(@".....\Ploep.docx");
        report.Close(false);
        wordApplication.Quit();
    }
```

Instead of pasting the data from the excel sheet, it pastes the content of my local machine's clipboard. Googling this specific problem doesn't return anything for me.

EDIT: I updated the part of the code with more readable code.I feel like the PasteExcelTable doesnt work. If I use .Paste(); it pastes the regular clipboard though.

EDIT2: It feels like the whole copying the excel doesnt work. Am i Doing something wrong here?

Comment: Shouln't those be regular (brackets) instead of [square]?  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.address  **Tutorial:** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_excel_sheet.htm

Comment: You definitely have to copy a range, not a worksheet.

Comment: Is this the exact same code as worked in your Console application? You mention " it pastes the content of my local machine's clipboard" - does that mean this code is not running on the local machine?

Comment: @Rory Yes, I tried both ways.

Comment: @CindyMeister I run this app from my localmachine. I was doing some testing (functionalities) in the console app.

Comment: @ashleedawg ill read through these pages, ill get back to you